# Getting atx.j error from YouTube player

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I'm using the YouTube library (through Jar File v1.2.1; https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/) and using Fabric for error reporting.  Every so often I get an error reported in Fabric coming from the YouTube library, usually "atx.j" file (but other times it's been: aqq.j, arp.j, aro.j).  Stack trace looks like:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
>          at com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.x(SourceFile:528)
>          at amp.w(SourceFile:454)
>          at kaf.onTransact(SourceFile:390)
>          at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
>          at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.d$a$a.r()
>          at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.s.h()
>          at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.e()
>          at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.onSaveInstanceState()
>          at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1936)
>          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1654)
>          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1722)
>          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:527)
>          at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1261)
>          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1229)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3637)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3696)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:174)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1348)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5748)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
>          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java) Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
>          at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java)
>          at atx.j(SourceFile:688)
>          at com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.x(SourceFile:525)
>          at amp.w(SourceFile:454)
>          at kaf.onTransact(SourceFile:390)
>          at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
>          at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.d$a$a.r()
>          at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.s.h()
>          at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.e()
>          at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.onSaveInstanceState()
>          at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1936)
>          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1654)
>          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1722)
>          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:527)
>          at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1261)
>          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1229)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3637)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3696)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:174)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1348)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5748)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
>          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue. It looks like there's an ongoing thread about getting youtube to fix the issue in their code here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4395

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jackson noted, this is a known issue to YouTube, so now we wait...

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4395